# If Group Contains Value Logic R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I'm trying to get the age given certain criteria. For example, if RNA is not null, then I would like to have the AvatarKey be associated with the minimum age associated with a present RNA entry. If, however, it is NA, I would like to take the minimum Age where DNA is not null. If both are null, remove.

Input:

```
ID       DNA     RNA     Age
2        NA      SL43    22.2
2        SL333   NA      55.7
2        SL333   SL43    43.7
6        SL333   NA      10.3
6        SL333   NA      65.6
6        NA      NA      35.5
5        NA      SL43    78.0
5        NA      SL43    23.3
5        NA      SL43    35.8
7        SL333   SL43    13.5
7        SL333   SL43    98.1
1        NA      NA      55.6
```

Desired Output

```
ID       DNA     RNA     Age
2        NA      SL43    22.2
2        SL333   SL43    43.7
6        SL333   NA      10.3
5        NA      SL43    23.3
7        SL333   SL43    13.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Different order than your output, but does this work?

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>%
  filter(!is.na(DNA) | !is.na(RNA)) %>%
  group_by(ID, DNA) %>%
  arrange(DNA, -Age) %>%
  slice(n())

     ID DNA   RNA     Age
  <int> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1     2 SL333 SL43   43.7
2     2 NA    SL43   22.2
3     5 NA    SL43   23.3
4     6 SL333 NA     10.3
5     7 SL333 SL43   13.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, DNA, RNA) %>%
  summarise(Age = min(Age)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!(is.na(DNA) & is.na(RNA)))
```